Question about a proof related to non-singular matrices
Right now I am trying to prove something about total unimodular matrices and there is something that seems to be true but I can't understand why.
Let $A$ be a non-singular square matrix with entries in $\{1,-1,0\}$. If I know that the greatest common divisor of the entries of $1^TA$ is one("1" stands for the vector of ones),
how does this imply that there must be a row in $A$ which has an odd number of non-zero entries?
I know that $1^TA$ has to have at least one odd entry and so the respective column needs to have an odd number of non-zero entries but I can't see how there has to be a row with this property.
PS.:
That's the full statement I try to prove:
Let $B$ be an integer matrix. For every invertible submatrix $A$ and every vector $y$ with entries in $\{1,-1,0\}$ the gdc of the entries of $y^TA$ is one $\Rightarrow$ for every invertible submatrix $A$ there is a row with an odd number of non-zero entries.

What is $1^T$ supposed to denote? Naturally, this would mean transpose of the identity matrix...but that doesn't seem right given the context.

Sorry for the confusion. "1" should stand for the vector of ones. So I kind of sum together all the rows of my matrix.

And the question isn't asking to prove that there must be a column with an odd number of non-zero entries?

It should be "row". I added the full statement which I try to prove.

Thank you for the added context. I’ve got some ideas, so I’ll have something typed up tomorrow morning. PMI seems like it’d potentially be a strong candidate for giving the easiest proof.

$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1\cr}\pmatrix{1&1&0\cr1&0&1\cr1&0&-1\cr}=\pmatrix{3&1&0\cr}
$$
